# Why does my jQuery alert show twice?

Tags: jquery, list

I am using jQuery. I have a problem when alerts the IDs of a list shows two times, instead of once.

The list:

```
<ul id="testnav">
    <li> <a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Page2..</a>
        <ul id="subnav">
            <li id="content_1"><a href="#"> Page3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(current_id);
    // These alert two times, one is empty and another one is content_1
});
```

Why dopes the code alert two times? How do I make it execute a single time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$("li").click() is applying the click event to all LIs on the page.

When you click

```
<li> <a href="#">Page2..</a>
     <ul id="subnav">
          <li id="content_1"><a href="#"> Page3</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

You're actually clicking the outer LI, and the inner-most LI, which would cause the event to fire twice.  The outer LI has no ID, so it's empty, and the inner LI has an ID of "content_1", so that displays.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 10):

Add `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` to your event and then it won't fire twice:

```
$("li").click(function(event)
{
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You have a `<li>` nested inside another `<li>`.

When you click on the inner `<li>`, you will get the event for the inner `<li>` and the outer `<li>`

Change your HTML to the following and you will get alerts of "Content_1" and "OUTER-LIST-ITEM" which make it clearer what is going on...

```
<ul id="testnav">
    <li> <a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li id="OUTER-LIST-ITEM">
        <a href="#">Page2..</a>
        <ul id="subnav">
            <li id="content_1"><a href="#"> Page3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are experiencing [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

The following code will solve your problem:

```
    $("li").click(function(event){ 
      var current_id=$(this).attr('id'); 
      alert(current_id);  
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $("li") returns a all matching objects.  So when you click one, the one with id=content_1, you also click its parent which does not have an id.

Answer (score 0):

It alerts once for each li and your link is two lists deep.  To fix it, assuming you only want subnav items to trigger, change the first line of your code to

```
$("#subnav li").click(function(){
```

If you need more lists create a class to identify lists you want to attach to the click event.